# Is Owin mandatory for host SignalR in IIS?

Tags: signalr, owin

I wonder can I host SignalR application in IIS without OWIN. If not what is the reason? Cant't IIS fit SignalR hosting recommendations? Why when I install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR package to Web Application project, Microsoft.Owin packages automatically install?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use SignalR 2.x without OWIN. OWIN abstracts the host/server and prevents from leaking server specific concepts into SignalR code. This allows using SignalR in IIS but also self host it in a command line app.

Comment: Thank you. What you think, is there advantage host SignalR application in IIS against self host in a command line app ?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve. I think if you want to run a regular server then use IIS - you will have more control, diagnostics, features etc. Self hosting is for instance great when developing things.